# Gift from my Dad

Tags: united-kingdom, india, gift-tax, gifts

My dad lives in India and is an Indian citizen. I am a UK citizen. My dad would like to give me and my wife a gift of around £8K each. Would I have to pay tax on this in the UK? My dad has already paid taxes on this amount. Also, is there a limit to the amount he can give us as gift?

Comment: I edited the answer to the duplicate question to make it clear there's no limit (nor tax).